# Import a RGB array into a PIL image with fromarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a RGB array that I would like to import in `PIL` with `fromarray` and save to disk:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngInfo
a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]],     # Red   Green
              [[0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 0]]])      # Blue  Black  
img = Image.fromarray(a, mode="RGB")   
metadata = PngInfo()                    # I need to add metadata, thus the use of Pillow and **not cv2**
metadata.add_text("key", "value")
img.save("test.png", pnginfo=metadata)
```

But the output image is `Red Black Black Black` instead of `Red Green Blue Black`.

Why?

**How to properly import a uint8 RGB array in a PIL object and save it to PNG?**

NB: Not a duplicate of [convert RGB arrays to PIL image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739851/convert-rgb-arrays-to-pil-image).

NB2: I also tried with a RGBA array, but the result is similar (the output image is `Red Black Black Black` instead of `Red Green Blue Black`) with:

```
a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0, 255]],     # Red   Green
              [[0, 0, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0, 255]]])      # Blue  Black
```

Comment: Note that it IS a duplicate of the question you've linked. Or at least it is the same problem (when reviewing question I have  a rather lenient way to qualify what is duplicate, and I try to avoid the common habit to qualify a question as "duplicate" because the answer is the same, even tho the question is not). But that is the same problem: PIL doesn't care about `dtype` (or at least in your version: more recent version of PIL would have just failed in your case), and just use ndarrays as a source of bytes. In your case, taking the first 12 bytes of your 8×4×3=96 bytes of `a`.

Comment: In the question you've linked, the user provided a float array, and PIL just took the bytes from the float representation. Resulting in an uglier image than you almost black one (of course: if you use bits from FP representation, that is a bit random). In your case, it is the bytes from int64 representation, so, mainly 0s.

Comment: In yet another (non duplicate, since different question, but in reality same problem, same answer) I've played a bit with internal representation to show my point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74961262/how-can-i-scale-an-image-with-pil-without-ruining-its-appearence/74961988#74961988

Comment: Fortunately this strange behavior of PIL (using the array shape as image resolution, but then just taking the array bytes, without any consideration for the array dtype) has been fixed since. So, when you'll update PIL (and maybe python) all those cases would have a more consistent behaviour: an error raised because of wrong `dtype`

Comment: With your version of PIL (cannot test here now that I've updated PIL), you could probably use `np.array([[[1095216660735, 255,0],[0,0,0]], [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])` as source. It doesn't make sense, but works. That array is a 2x2x3 array, so image will be a 2x2 RGB image. And the 12 first bytes of this array are the 255,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,255,0,0,0 you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your array needs to be of type uint8, then everything works.

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngInfo
a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]],     # Red   Green
              [[0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 0]]],      # Blue  Black
             dtype=np.uint8)      
img = Image.fromarray(a).convert("RGB")
metadata = PngInfo()                    # I need to add metadata, thus the use of Pillow and **not cv2**
metadata.add_text("key", "value")
img.save("test.png", pnginfo=metadata)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work without `.convert("RGB")`!